# How to avoid gaps between stitches in crocheted clothes

Tags: crocheting, clothing, technique-selection

When I crochet something, I always end up with gaps in between my stitches, leading to a sort of open-weave effect. That's fine for baggy cardigans and the like, but for tops, dresses, skirts, etc, I'd rather it not be so see-through.

I've seen patterns for sale with example pictures that don't have those gaps, but I'm broke, so I haven't actually bought them to see if the pattern says anything about how I might achieve that.

Is there a certain stitch pattern/type that works? Smaller hook? ... lining? And if it is a matter of lining it, how would you sew a lining into crochet? Would the gaps in the stitches cause a problem?

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts! Crocheting usually leads to an "open" or "airy" fabric and the holes are the defining features of most patterns. Maybe a different technique like knitting would be more suited for your purpose? It would help if you could [edit] your question and add a picture of something you crocheted and an example picture of how you'd like it to be.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried more dense stitches or using a smaller hook/crocheting more tightly to achieve a more dense result?

Answer (score 5):

I crochet swimwear and I have observed that if I crochet tighter, it reduces the space significantly between stitches. The type of stitch is probably the biggest factor contributing to holes though. Stitches like the Alpine Stitch or the Rice Stitch are a bit chunkier and shouldn't have too many holes, especially if you crochet tightly. The Shell Stitch is also good. If those stitches still give you too many holes, you can always test different types of yarns/hook sizes.

A medium weight Polyester/Viscose/Nylon blend yarn with a size 3.75 hook using rice stitches produced a garment that had no holes at all for me. Hope this helps in some way!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a denser fabric by doing several things:

1. Decreasing the size of the hook
2. Keeping more tension on the working yarn
3. Using yarn that has more fluff/squishy to it. With more tension, it will thin as your working, then fluff back out after the tension is off (reducing the airy-ness of the fabric).

For #4/Worsted weight yarn, I tend towards a 3.5 mm or 3.75 mm hook for less airy fabric.